# ¿Por qué el programa no reconoce la secuencia if?

Tags: c

```
//Pide al usuario su nombre y signo , si es aries ,imprimalo por pantalla
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main (){
  char nombre[35], signo[35];
  fprintf(stdout,"Introduzca su nombre : ");
  fgets(nombre,35,stdin);
  fprintf(stdout,"Introduzca su signo: ");
  fgets(signo,35,stdin);
  if (strcmp(signo,"Aries")==0){
    fprintf(stdout,"Hola %s su signo es Aries.\n",nombre);
  }
  else {
    fprintf(stdout,"No es aries\n");
    return 0;
}
```

El programa siempre me responde con que no es aries. Esta hecho desde windows en ubuntu .Pide al usuario que introduzca su nombre y signo y si es aries debe imprimirlo por pantalla.

Comment: `fgets` lee toda la linea, incluyendo el `\n`.

Comment: Una  alternativa es usar: scanf("%s",signo);

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich No está mal la alternativa, siempre y cuando se especifique el tamaño del buffer, ejemplo: `scanf("%34s",signo);`.

Answer (score 1):

Obviamente, cuando utilizas **fgets** está leyendo absolutamente toda la línea. Cuando nosotros le damos a la tecla [ENTER] es un carácter más, concretamente el carácter **'\n'**. Por ende, en realidad el conjunto de chars que debes comparar es **"Aries\n"**. Te dejo por aquí el código modificado a tus necesidades.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main (){
    
  char nombre[35], signo[35];
  fprintf(stdout,"Introduzca su nombre : ");
  fgets(nombre,35,stdin);
  fprintf(stdout,"Introduzca su signo: ");
  fgets(signo,35,stdin);
  
  if ( strcmp(signo, "Aries\n") == 0 ){
    fprintf(stdout, "Hola %s su signo es Aries.\n", nombre);
  }
  else {
    fprintf(stdout,"No es aries\n");
  }
  
  return 0;
  
}
```

Cuando programas en C, debes tener cuenta factores de este tipo entre muchos otros. ¡Espero haber sido de ayuda!